# ObservableArray.push() doesn't notify the view

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, nativescript

I create a list of items to be suggested under my autocomplete search bar, in this standard manner:

[image: Screenshot of an autocomplete component for nativescript-ui]
The items are listed in an ObservableArray data type.

I would like to incrementally populate the suggestion items by pushing them one by one to the ObservableArray with a condition:

```
page.bindingContext.set("suggestionItems", new ObservableArray([]));

for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++){
    if ( conditionMet(source[i]) ){
        page.bindingContext.suggestionItems.push(
             new autocompleteModule.TokenModel(source[i])
        );
    }
}

console.log("Items for suggestion: " + page.bindingContext.suggestionItems);
```

However this method doesn't work. No items are ever listed under the search bar. Although the console.log() shows a well populated ObservableArray in the bindingContext:

```
Items for suggestion: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I am therefore using a workarround, although poorly elegant and not flexible. I populate a temporary array in the function scope, and then i set() the suggestionItems in the bindingContext directly with that whole temporary array.

```
let tempItems = [];
for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++){
    if ( conditionMet(source[i]) ){
        tempItems.push(
             new autocompleteModule.TokenModel(source[i])
        );
    }
}

page.bindingContext.set("suggestionItems", new ObservableArray(tempItems));

console.log("Items for suggestion: " + page.bindingContext.suggestionItems);
```

So now if I want to push an item, I need to replace the whole ObservableArray from scratch...

Note that for the workarround, the console.log() output is the same.

Comment: Rather than using `push` (which does not return a new array), what if you tried `concat` (`yourArray = yourArray.concat(newItem)`)?

Comment: It is a nice workarroud, but doesn't solve the issue. Nativescript's data structures are made observable to enable double binding. So is the case of the push() method of those classes. I want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's a known issue with nativescript-ui, the component never gets updated until you change the reference itself. So you are following the right workaround already.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. So is it really an issue... ? I mean is it purposeful choice from Nativescript ? It would so much cleaner if push() and splice() were actual notifiers.

Comment: I haven't really worked with observables outside of a Nativescript environment, is this an issue in a vanilla Angular environment?